# Downloading the body of sites using user input

Tags: ruby, shoes

I want to use shoes to be able to download the body of a website that a user enters in an edit_line.  How can I make this work?  Can anyone help explain why the below code does not work?  It just pops up a new window, and does not download the site from the text entered....

Here's my code thus far:

```
Shoes.app do
  stack (:left => 175, :top => 200) do
    para "Enter a url:"
    flow do
      @url = edit_line
      button "OK" do

    window do
        stack do
         title "Searching site", :size => 16
          @status = para "One moment..."
          # Search site for query and print body
            download @url.text do |site|
              @status.text = "Body: " + site.response.body.inspect
            end
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - I figured it out.  I just didn't pop to a new window and it downloads and prints the body fine.  : )

Comment: You should accept your answer, then, so that this question gets closed.